# How to get 2-week view in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have the 4-day view not the 2-week view.

Comment: This site is for questions about computer hardware or software. Questions about specific web sites are not really appropriate for this site. They are better asked on *their* support forum. See the faq (http://superuser.com/faq). "… and it is not about … websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress"

Comment: Then why is there a category called google-calendar?

Comment: Because it used to be allowed. Since the FAQ has changed. All Google Calendar questions are being closed as they appear. Anyone can create a tag. So just because there is one doesn't mean it's allowed.

Comment: Or you could be talking about interfacing with google-calendar with say outlook.

Comment: @Diago: Why is this closed? Google Calendar is software-related, since Google Apps is SaaS (software-as-a-service). The software in question may not be on the machine of the person asking the question, but its UI sure is. Totally legit question in my books.

Comment: As an aside, how do I @Name someone with spaces in their name (like "Robert C. Cartaino", or indeed myself)?

Comment: @Alex. 1. Read the FAQ. Questions about Websites and Webservices including SaaS is not allowed. There is a thread on meta about where they can be posted. 2. THe @Name only matches the first 3 characters of the name in the list, and doesn't work with spaces. It also only matches the last person in the comment that matches the first 3 characters. It is a loosly implemented system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Custom Views in Google Calendar](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/02/custom-views-in-google-calendar.html) :

> Google Calendar has an option to
> define custom views: you can replace
> the "next 7 days" with other intervals
> like the "next 3 days" or "next 2
> weeks". In the settings you'll also
> find an option to make your custom
> view the default.

The UI has changed since then, but the option is still available:

[image]

Comment: "In the settings you'll also find an option to make your custom view the default.", where?

Comment: @KarlMorrison: This answer is from 2010. I don't use Google Calendar now, but try to search for it. If you find it, let me know and I'll update this answer.